# Refresh data originally passed into modalInstrance in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Using Angular - UI Bootstrap

I am passing data into a modalInstance like the below. In the modal, users have the ability to create new items. On the save button press, a new item is sent to the server. I need the ability to refresh the modal instance with the updated data from $scope.items. Note, the modal doesn't close on the save, so I can't just re-open it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$scope.items = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];

$scope.open = function (size) {

var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
    resolve: {
        items: function () {
            return $scope.items;
        }
    }
});

modalInstance.result.then(function () {
    // post updated $scope.items to server
    // get fresh $scope.items from server
    // notify modal of the updated items
}, function () {

});
};
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try just to create scope for your `$modalInstance` as a child of current `$scope` like this:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
    scope: $scope
});
```

So now after add some `item` to your `items` everything will work fine.

For more info you can take a look at description of `$modal` directive on the **[angular bootstrap page](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)**:

`scope - a scope instance to be used for the modal's content (actually the $modal service is going to create a child scope of a provided scope). Defaults to $rootScope`

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/khzNQ0?p=preview

Hope, it will resolve your problem ;)

Comment: Great solution. I wish I would have known about passing $scope before I had messed with all of that resolved nonsense. :)